# the purpose of the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FeatureManagement\Overrides\4\ Hive in Windows 10 May 2020 Update

Tags: registry

does anyone know the purpose of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FeatureManagement\Overrides\4\ hive in the Windows Registry Editor in Windows 10 May 2020 Update. what is the purpose for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HKLM:SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FeatureManagement\Overrides` - This hive stores the overridden features of the windows. Okay this seems pretty literal. Let me explain it more.

There are certain (actually a lot of) features that are hidden in Windows and are not rolled out to everyone, not even to all the insiders. But these features can be enabled by third party tools like [Mach-2](https://github.com/riverar/mach2) and [ViVeTool](https://github.com/thebookisclosed/ViVe). Such tools basically override the entries present in the that particular hive.

You can see the list of all hidden features [here](https://github.com/riverar/mach2/tree/master/features). The file name refers to your build version.

Note that the registry values inside that hive may be present by default in your Windows version. Their presence does not necessarily imply that you've done some tweaking.

Moreover, there is a Scheduled Task named `ReconcileFeatures` (at `\Microsoft\Windows\Flighting\FeatureConfig`) which tends to restore the registry values inside `Overrides` back to their original values.

Another thing: The number after `Override`, i.e. generally `0` or `4` represents the priority group. There is a rare priority group `10`, which is treated more like an "enterprise policy".